# capybara（+ Poltergeist）でaタグがclick_on出来ない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

## 前提・実現したいこと

rails+capybara(+Poltergeist)でスクレイピングをしようとしています。 
aタグをクリックして次のページに移動する動きしようとしているのですがうまく動きません。

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Failures:

  1) test next20
     Failure/Error: click_on "次の20件"

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link or button "次の20件"
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:43:in `block in find'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in `synchronize'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:32:in `find'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:13:in `click_link_or_button'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:686:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./test3.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:290:in `within'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./test3.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 7.06 seconds (files took 0.4783 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:
```

## ソースコード（test3.rb）

```
require 'capybara/rspec' 
require 'capybara/poltergeist' 
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist 
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app| 
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, { 
                    js_errors: false, 
                    timeout: 1000, 
                    debug: true, 
                    phantomjs_options: [ 
                              '--load-images=no', 
                              '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', 
                              '--ssl-protocol=any']}) 
end

Capybara.configure do |config| 
    config.run_server = false 
    config.default_driver = :poltergeist 
    config.app_host = 'http://www.mansion-review.jp/prefecture/20.html' 
end

describe "test", :type => :feature do 
  subject{ page } 
  before { visit('/') }

  it "next20", js: true do 
    within ('#saleHistorySoubaBlock') do 
      have_text "次の20件" 
      click_on "次の20件" 
    end 
  end 
end
```

## 補足情報

- capybara (2.6.2)
- globalid (0.3.6)
- rails (4.2.6)
- rspec-rails (3.4.2)

## 追記

広く意見を求めたい為,Stack Overflowとteratailにて同様の質問をしております。
解決しましたら、両方にて共有したいと思いますので、ご容赦ください。

---

コメントは改行できないのですね、教えていただきありがとうございます。
エラーメッセージが若干違うようですので、貼っておきます。

## エラーメッセージ

```
Failures:

  1) test next20
     Failure/Error: click_on "次の20件"

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link or button "次の20件"
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:43:in `block in find'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in `synchronize'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:32:in `find'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:13:in `click_link_or_button'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:686:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./test3.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:290:in `within'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./test3.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:290:in `within'
     # ~/vendor/bundler/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./test3.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 7.67 seconds (files took 1.44 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:
```

## 修正部分

```
describe "test", :type => :feature do
  subject{ page }
  before { visit('/') }

  it "next20", js: true do
    within first('#resultBlock div p') do
      within all('a').last do
        should have_text '次の20件'
        click_on "次の20件"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: ソースコードなどはスペース4文字でインデントすると読みやすくなります。参考： http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのページをブラウザで見てみましたが、エラーメッセージの通り、 `#saleHistorySoubaBlock` の中に `次の20件` はありません。というか、`#saleHistorySoubaBlock` は空っぽの `<div>` ですね。

それなら `click_on` じゃなくて `have_text` でエラーになりそうですが、これは「対象が指定した文字列を含むかどうかを検査するMatcher」を返すメソッドで、呼びだしただけでは何も起きません。RSpecの `should` や `expect(...).to` に渡して初めて実際の検査が行われます。

例えば次のようにすると、`should have_text` の時点でFailureになります。

```
describe "test", :type => :feature do 
  subject{ page } 
  before { visit('/') }

  it "next20", js: true do 
    within ('#saleHistorySoubaBlock') do 
      should have_text "次の20件" 
      click_on "次の20件" 
    end 
  end 
end
```

---

例えば `<a id="hoge">link text</a>` というリンクがあり、ここで `within('#hoge')` とすると、

- `should have_text 'link text'`：　**そのリンクの中に** `link text` という文字列を含む
  ⇒ OK
- `click_on 'link text'`： **そのリンクの中で** `link text` と書かれたリンク・ボタンをクリック
  ⇒ `<a id="hoge">link text</a>` の中にリンク・ボタンは存在しないのでエラー

となります。それ自身をクリックするという意味にはなりません。

withinで選択した要素自体をクリックする方法はちょっとわからなかったので、have_textも省略してこんな感じでいかがでしょう。

```
describe "test", :type => :feature do 
  subject{ page } 
  before { visit('/') }

  it "next20", js: true do 
    within ('#resultBlock div p') do 
      first(:link, "次の20件").click
      # あるいは
      # click_on "次の20件", :match => :first
    end 
  end 
end
```

一応firstと指定していますが、capybara2.6.2で試す限りでは単にclick_onとだけ書いても最初にマッチしたものをクリックしてくれるようですね。

参考

- [Capybaraでクリックできない場合の対処法 - harublog](http://hrt0kmt.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/11/17/210904)
- [How to click first link in list of items after upgrading to Capybara 2.0? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513377/how-to-click-first-link-in-list-of-items-after-upgrading-to-capybara-2-0)

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。  　　
ご指摘の通り #saleHistorySoubaBlock は空ですね、見間違えておりました。
ちょっと変更して should have_text で "次の20件" は検査できたのですが、やはりclick_onでエラー出てしまいます。
it "next20", js: true do
  within first('#resultBlock div p') do
    within all('a').last do
      should have_text '次の20件'
      click_on "次の20件"
    end
  end
end

Comment: すみません、不慣れなものでうまくコメントで改行が出来ませんでした。  読みにくくてすみません。

Comment: @zack02 コメントでは改行できないので、コードを書く必要がある場合は質問文に追記することが多いですね。エラー文が同じかどうか、違っていたらその文言もあわせて書いて頂けると助かります。

Comment: @zack02 回答を更新しました

Comment: 質問文の追記と回答を間違えておりました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。クリックの方法も分かり助かりました。今回はありがとうございました。